# asp.net MVC - How can I share the same instance of a SqlConnection through different repository classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern

I'm creating a new project using MVC5 and plain ADO.NET (just as a learning exercise) and I need to create a repository that registers a model with several related objects that also need to be created at the same time and those objects in turn may need to insert other objects.

The easiest solution I can think of is to have a massive method(in the repository) that receives an instance of the parent object(which contains all the related objects that needs to insert) and also have a single stored procedure that receives all the related data as table-valued parameters and then insert everything using a single transaction.

Though that might seem the most straightforward approach, I'm not a big fan of it, so what I want to know is if there's any way/common practice that I can use to share the same instance of a SqlConnection created for the parent object with the other related objects?

I was thinking that perhaps passing the SqlConnection object in the constructor of the related objects, that way each repository would only have to deal with the logic to insert a single object, but I'm not sure.

### Edit

### -------------------------------

This is the repository for the parent object (Model), the one that I think, should instantiate the SqlConnection and start the transaction

```
 public class ModelRepository : IModelRepository
    {
        public int Add(Model entity)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {   
                conn.Open();
                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {                    
                    command.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                    command.CommandText = "up_Model_Insert";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                 
                    

                    command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pName ", entity.Name));
                    command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter("@pDescription", entity.Description));
                    //Other parameters...

                    //Call the repositories of the other objects

                    //....

                    //how can I make the other repositories use the same connection and 
                    //transaction as the Model entity?


                    

                    
                    return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make the others repositories use the same connection and transaction as the "Model" entity.

I've read the Ninject has this ["object scope" concept](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) , but I'm not sure what would be the right one in my case.

Comment: have you looked into IoC? it works really well with MVC and probably would be ideal for dependency injection in your case. [Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/117/dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control-with-asp-net-mvc) is a nice article that helps with IoC and MVC:

Comment: @skar currently  I'm using Ninject and what I think it is known as the constructor dependency injection pattern. The problem with this pattern is that, as far as I know, it goes like this: whenever I need a new instance of a class X, go and instantiate all its dependencies, and for this particular scenario is not what I need because there'll be several instances of the SqlConnection class.

Comment: you should be able to register the SqlConnection class as a singleton against your IoC container, which would allow you to instantiate the SqlConnection class once and use that same instance where ever you need it.

Comment: @skar Please see the **Edit** section in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to 'share' a connection. Back to the basics, you should always encapsulate a connection in a `using` block (assume you use EF).

What you are after are transactions, right? What I'm just thinking of my head here right now:
What you could do is wrap your insert logic in `TransactionInfo` classes. These `TransactionInfo` classes could take an `Action` and a repository as parameters. The action eventually does the logic of inserting a single object via the given repository (the repository should follow some interface that provides you with CRUD logic).

When you have multiple `TransactionInfo`'s, you could send them together somewhere that would do the logic of beginning an [database transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx), execute all given `Actions` from every `TransactionInfo` object and eventually execute the transaction.

`TransactionInfo` could have a constructor like:

```
public TransactionInfo(Action action, ICrudRepository repository)
```

I hope I've understood you well. Sharing an `SqlConnection` seems just wrong to me.

Comment: Please see the **Edit** section in my question.